# How to optimize first call to "syncMessagesWithFolder" call in Mailcore2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, imap, mailcore2

I'm using the "syncMessagesWithFolder" method below. I'm running a timer before and after the call and I'm seeing that this call takes the network somewhere between 1 to sometimes 3.5 seconds to complete.

From my trials below, it seems like the first call to "syncMessagesWithFolder" takes the longest but the subsequent ones are pretty fast.

It seems like there might be some initialization mailcore2 does before making the first call. Is this correct? How do I ensure that it's sub 1 second every single time?

```
self.inboxSync = [self.imapSession syncMessagesWithFolder:folder requestKind:self.account.requestKind uids: [MCOIndexSet indexSetWithRange:MCORangeMake(1, UINT64_MAX)] modSeq:lastModSeq];
```

Here are some of my sample times:

```
==Trial 1==
Time to mod sync: [Gmail]/All Mail  3.441797, messages: 0
Time to mod sync: [Gmail]/Trash     0.509983, messages: 0
Time to mod sync: INBOX             0.611326, messages: 0
Time to mod sync: [Gmail]/Sent Mail 0.437869, messages: 0

==Trial 2==
Time to mod sync: [Gmail]/All Mail  3.363301, messages: 0
Time to mod sync: [Gmail]/Trash     0.509976, messages: 0
Time to mod sync: INBOX             0.408450, messages: 0
Time to mod sync: [Gmail]/Sent Mail 0.715538, messages: 0
```

Comment: You can get only UIDs through self.account.requestKind. Then request chunks of the messages list.

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà Thank you. This is the correct answer. 

When fetching 200 messages, the difference was from 15 seconds to 5 seconds, a 10 second improvement when only fetching the UID.

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà Which request kind only fetches message UIDs? In other words, which `requestKind` is the leanest way to fetch all message UIDs?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. If you leave `requestKind` blank on a `fetchMessagesOperation`, it will fetch the least amount of data, but include the message UID.